# How to convert snapshot files to any other format?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-c++

Is there any way to convert the Sql Server 'Snapshot' files (*.ss files) to some other format...like 'xml','xls' or 'txt'...etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the files generated by a creating a Database Snapshot - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

snapshot files are [sparse files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365564%28VS.85%29.aspx) that only contain pages that have been 'copied on write'.  They may appear to be the size of the source database, but they are not.  They are useless without the source database.

Best way to get the data out is via something like a BCP out, or an SSIS package to export what you need